# How to use pandas apply() with a function that returns a tuple with the result and some additional unwanted value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply [boxcox](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html) transformation to every column in a dataframe. The issue is that, unless a second parameter is provided like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288363/pandas-apply-function-with-different-argument-values-to-different-columns), boxcox function returns a tuple of a list with the results and the lambda value. So if I have a dataframe like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'B': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'C': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
})
```

and I run

```
data = data.apply(boxcox, axis=0)
```

the result I get is

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [0.8920853744781212, 1.6536161444449853, 2.341... | [0.8920853744781212, 1.6536161444449853, 2.341... | [1.656999136329274, 2.347308075247294, 2.98765... |
| 1 | 0.690297 | 0.699807 | 0.703108 |

I want the values from the lists in row 0 to be spread through each column and I don't want the values in row 1 at all. I can think of a few dirty workarounds, but I would like to know if there is some proper way of doing this. Can I somehow ignore the second value returned by the boxcox function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: boxcox(x)[0] , axis=0)
```

Comment: Goddamn I need to finally learn lambdas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to define your own simplified function:

```py
from scipy.stats import boxcox

def boxcox_single(x):
    return boxcox(x)[0]
```

Then you can pass this function to `df.apply()`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it, but is it really the cleanest way of doing this? Is there no pythonic one line solution for a problem like this?

Comment: Yes, you can condense the function definition and the `df.apply()` call into one line with `lambda`, see @Yefet's answer.